# How do i fix "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'" error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I am using CreateContext in Typescript and I can see why there is a problem with the code but I cannot work out how to resolve it. Its a basic use of typesafe TX to make state and (useReducer) dispatch available in a component hierarchy

The sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-usereducer-todo-lk391?file=/src/App.tsx

The context interface:

```
export interface ContextInterface {
  state: AppState;
  dispatch: (action: ActionType) => void;
}
```

Using the interface to createContext (I think it has to be a partial because createContext wont take zero args)

```
const TodoContext = createContext<Partial<ContextInterface>>({});
```

The context is initialised in my parent component:

```
  let [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  ...
  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
  ...
```

When I useContext TS reports Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722), however the console.log executes as expected.

```
  let { dispatch } = useContext(TodoContext);
  console.log("dispatch", dispatch);
```

Is there a way to correctly define the Context object and remove the error?

Comment: Or just give it an initial value, why would you use a `Partial` type

Comment: I gave it a Partial as I cant initilise until I have a dispatch function from useReducer. The other option was to initialise with undefined (its wont take nil arguments) which creates a different set of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `useContext` call in a custom hook that will take care of the type issues:

1. first change the definition of `TodoContext` to include an optional empty state

```
const TodoContext = createContext<ContextInterface | undefined>(undefined);
```

2. create a custom hook that throws an informative error on how this hook should be used

```
export const useTodoContext = (): ContextInterface => {
  const context = useContext(TodoContext)
  if (!context) {
    throw Error('useTodoContext must be used inside TodoContext.Provider')
  }
  return context
}
```

then you can use this hook without issues.

This approach scales well to all types of context data.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, the issue is that by using `Partial`, you've made all properties of the context type optional, so they might be `undefined` (from a type perspective), and you need to allow for that if you go that route.

According to the [`createContext` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext), the default is **only** used when there's no relevant provider, so instead of using `Partial`, you could just include a default context object that always throws:

```
const TodoContext = createContext<ContextInterface>({
    state: {/*...mocked AppState stuff...*/},
    dispatch: (action: ActionType) => {
        throw new Error(`Default context used unexpectedly, check you have a provider`);
    }
});
```

That way, TypeScript won't think `dispatch` may be `undefined`.

If there aren't any reasonable defaults for the `AppState` properties, you could use a `Proxy` that throws an error similar to the one above on any property access, so that attempts to use `context.state.x` provide the same clear error.